# How to disable this notification: JS/TS analysis failed. Please check the SonarLint Output for more details

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I open a Typescript file in VS Code I always get this annoying notification. How Can I Disable it so it never shows up ever again.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove SonarLint extension.